# change shader on all assigned meshes, without using hyperShade()

Tags: python, maya

I get all shapes assigned to baseMaterial, select the shapes and then assign the occlusionShader.

```
for materialClass in materialClassList:
    select(materialClass.baseMaterial)
    hyperShade(objects="")
    hyperShade(a=materialClass.occlusionShader)
```

works just fine, but if I use it as a pre render script:

```
  Error: line 0: hyperShade command not supported in batch mode
```

What can I change the two last lines of my function to to make this work?

Comment: just to make a link if people want to follow your problem : http://forums.cgsociety.org/showthread.php?t=1490566

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it to work with:

```
for materialClass in materialClassList:
    sets(materialClass.occlusionShadingGroup, e = True, forceElement = materialClass.meshList)
```

I collect the meshes when I create the materialClass now, which makes much more sense then selecting them for each renderlayer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with cmds.sets() to assign a shader :

```
all = cmds.ls(type='mesh')
shadingEngine = 'initialShadingGroup'
cmds.sets(all, e=True, forceElement=shadingEngine)
```

as you can guess, to query meshes with the material :

```
lamb1_mshs = cmds.sets(shadingEngine, q=True)
```

Comment: thanks drWeeny. I had already tried it that way, following this post:
https://forum.highend3d.com/t/python-how-to-assign-shader-to-an-object/48778/3

but what i got was:
 # Error: The argument provided is NOT a set #

only when I swapped the arguments it worked, which is different to any suggestion I found online. (please check my answer)
do you have an idea why that is?

Comment: on which version of maya you are ? what type of occlusion shader you are assigning and which renderer ? are materialClass.meshList is only meshes or there is some nurbs ? if you run it without batching, is the code above is working ?

Comment: maya 2016 sp6. mib_amb_occlusion, rendering in mental ray. Its only polygons. I run it without batching and it doesnt work.
(calling script from python tab/shelf button)