# Maya python (or MEL) select objects

Tags: python, loops, select, maya, mel

I need select all objects in Maya with name "shd" and after that I need assigned to them specific material.

I don't know how to do that because when I wrote: **select -r "shd";** it send me the message: *More than one object matches name: shd //*

So maybe I should select them one by one in some for loop or something. I am 3D artist so sorry for the lame question.

Comment: @DrWeeny's answer will serve you well. As for assigning a material, I would recommend using the `cmds.hypershade` call if you are in a UI session (doesn't work from `mayabatch`). Check out http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/hyperShade.html for an example of how to assign shaders

Comment: furthermore if you want to assign shaders without hypershade command which the few limitations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49035311/change-shader-on-all-assigned-meshes-without-using-hypershade/49046788#49046788

Answer (score 1):

you have multiple meshes named shd, you will end with an error. You might want to use the command :

```
shd = cmds.ls('shd', long=True)
cmds.select(shd)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `select -r "shd*"` to select all objects with a name stating with "shd".

Comment: Thanks you very much